# protractor works on localhost but fails in CircleCi

Tags: protractor, circleci

i have a small question about how to use protractor in circleCi. This code works fine in my localhost and also if i run it in firefox. there is also a small guess (not 100% sure about) but when i use methods that return promises like getCurrentUrl for example , chrome on circleCi fail also. This is the error i receive:

[circleCi error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaCon.png)

**My configuration is :**

- Node Version: 6.9.1
- Protractor Version: 5.1
- Angular Version: 4
- Browser(s): chrome
- Operating System and Version ubuntu 16.4

**My test samble **

```
import { browser, Config, element, by } from 'protractor';
import { assert } from 'chai';
describe('simple test', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });

    it('should login', function() {
        browser.get('http://localhost:8080/#/signin');
        const email = element(by.name('email'));
        const password = element(by.name('password'));
        const button = element(by.css('[type="submit"]'));
        email.sendKeys('qa-test@domain.fr');
        password.sendKeys('12345678');
        button.click();
        browser.sleep(1500);
        const logout = element(by.className('ll-navbar-icon fa fa-power-off'));
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('/dashboard');
        browser.isElementPresent(logout);
    });
});
```

**My protractor configuration file:**

```
import { environment } from './environment';
import { browser, Config } from 'protractor';
import { SpecReporter } from 'jasmine-spec-reporter';

export let config: Config = {
  directConnect: true,
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  baseUrl: environment.baseUrl,
  capabilities: environment.capabilities,
  framework: environment.framework,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },

  specs: [
    '../../build/app.spec.js'
  ],
  // This utility function helps prepare our scripts with required actions like browser maximize
  onPrepare: () => {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the test ran with no problems locally, but when running in circleci it failed.

I was able to fix it by increasing the jasmine DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL in my tests:

`beforeEach(function() {
     jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 999999;
});`

Also make sure to use the "Debug via SSH" functionality circleci provides. It's very handy to debug your setup.

Comment: what do you do when you debug via SSH? example?

Comment: You can run the different pieces of your test from the cmd line, then check their output / logs. (divide your test suite/debug and conquer)